# How to get values from the selected Row in a DataTable on CellClick Event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I just want to ask on how can I get the values from a row in `DataTable`

ex.:

DataTable:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
-------------------------
c1r1 | c2r1 | c3r1 | c4r1

c1r2 | c2r2 | c3r2 | c4r2
```

In the `DataGridView`, `col2` is hidden for display purposes. `col2` holds the `ID` values which is not included in the display.
So if I click, lets say, `c4r1` in the `DataGridView` I can get the value of `col2` which is `c2r1` and put in a `Label`.

I've search on how to do it but I can't get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the [DataGridView.RowEnter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.RowEnter);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) event.
There, update a `Label.Text` property  with the `Value` of the `Column(1)` Cell in the current Row :

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    Label1.Text = dataGridView1(1, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
    'Or...
    'Label1.Text = dataGridView1("col2", e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Jimi sir it works perfectly I get the result I wanted. thanks a lot sir!

Comment: Glad it helped :). You're new here. Next time, post the code you have. Never mind if it's not working, we'll fix it. You will have more attention and good answers if you do so. Otherwise, your question could get closed before you can get an answer. The quality of the question is important. You have to show what you tried but failed.

Comment: noted sir. I will include the code I have next time. thanks again for your help sir @Jimi